# Permanently change GDB disassembly flavor from att to intel syntax

Tags: gdb, disassembly

I have already looked at other posts here on stack overflow on how to permanently change the disassembly flavor of GDB from att to intel syntax, however, I could not figure out how to do so.

I know that I have to modify a file called '~/.gdbinit' and put down the line 'set disassembly-flavor intel'. The problem is that I can't find a file called '~/.gdbinit' on my computer. I also don't know how to create such a file because I keep getting the error message 'The filename not valid' when I try to do so.

I hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

On Unix style operating systems, the '~' is an alias for your home directory. The '.gdbinit' is just a normal file.  Try this:

```
echo "set disassembly-flavor intel" > ~/.gdbinit
```

You will need to train yourself on an editor like `vi` or `nano` to edit the file further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am a complete beginner so I am not quite sure where I need put down `echo "set disassembly-flavor intel" > ~/.gdbinit`. And what do you mean by 'train yourself on an editor like vi or nano to edit the file further?

Comment: What operating system are your using Windows, Linux, Solaris?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10.